# How to supply options to the python interpreter when using iPython

Tags: python, command-line, arguments, ipython

For example, if I wanted to avoid generation of `.pyc` files when using the usual `python` command I would write:

```
python -B script.py
```

But what if I want to use `ipython` instead? All I know is that

```
ipython -B script.py
```

doesn't work

Comment: You could use environment variables. The equivalent to the `-B` option is [PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE).

Comment: @ThomasK That's good enough, it works. Can you develop it a bit more and post this as an answer? I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the command line options for the Python interpreter have equivalent [environment variables](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables). These will work when starting IPython.

For instance, instead of the `-B` flag, to avoid writing bytecode, you can use:

```
PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 ipython
```